# cURL - put output into variable?

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm currently using this C code:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://my-domain.org/");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

It prints the output on the console. How can I get the same output, but read it into, say, a string? (This is a probably a basic question, but I do not yet understand the libcurl API...)

Thanks for any help!

Mike

Answer (score 16):

You need to pass a function and buffer to write it to buffer.

```
/* setting a callback function to return the data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback_func);

/* passing the pointer to the response as the callback parameter */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);


/* the function to invoke as the data recieved */
size_t static write_callback_func(void *buffer,
                        size_t size,
                        size_t nmemb,
                        void *userp)
{
    char **response_ptr =  (char**)userp;

    /* assuming the response is a string */
    *response_ptr = strndup(buffer, (size_t)(size *nmemb));

}
```

Please take a look more info [here](http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2009/01/28/making-web-requests-using-curl-from-c-and-php/).

Comment: @Mike, Updated with some example, and a link for C and php, basically same concepts.

Comment: Also notice that you should return the size in the callback function. In this case: return (size_t)(size *nmemb);

Comment: Is a callback function necessary even if I want to write to a file?

Comment: What value does write_callback_func() return?

Answer (score 4):

you need a write callback function. I use this kind of function to read the response, error and be able to supply my own headers:

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    std::string buf = std::string(static_cast<char *>(ptr), size * nmemb);
    std::stringstream *response = static_cast<std::stringstream *>(stream);
    response->write(buf.c_str(), (std::streamsize)buf.size());
    return size * nmemb;
}

bool CurlGet(
    const std::string &url, 
    const std::vector<std::string> &headers, 
    std::stringstream &response, 
    std::string &error)
{

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;

    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = headers.begin(); it < headers.end(); it++) {
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, it->c_str());
    }   

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    char ebuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, ebuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        error = ebuf;
    else
        error.clear();

    return res == CURLE_OK; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using

```
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
```

which sets a callback function `write_data` which is a function with the signature

```
size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
```

If you want `userp` be some internal struct you are using in your program, call

```
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &internal_struct);
```

to get the pointer to `internal_struct` passed to every call of `write_data`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i solve issue of return code 23 from call back function to return size from call back function.

see below code:

```
/* setting a callback function to return the data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback_func);

/* passing the pointer to the response as the callback parameter */
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);


/* the function to invoke as the data recieved */
size_t static write_callback_func(void *buffer,
                        size_t size,
                        size_t nmemb,
                        void *userp)
{
    char **response_ptr =  (char**)userp;

    /* assuming the response is a string */
    *response_ptr = strndup(buffer, (size_t)(size *nmemb));

    return ((size_t)(size *nmemb));
//if you not send return value of size it will show you ERROR CODE 23return  curl_easy_perform();

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

None of the other examples worked for me.
Here's what I eventually ended up doing:

```
size_t static curl_write(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
     userp += strlen(userp);  // Skipping to first unpopulated char
     memcpy(userp, buffer, nmemb);  // Populating it.
     return nmemb;
}

int GetCurl()
{
     CURL *curl;
     CURLcode res;

     char *s = (char *) malloc(512);

     curl = curl_easy_init();
     if (curl)
     {
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_write);
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, s);
          res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
          curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
     }

     printf("GREAT SUCCESS!! Your string is %s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: Why "void *userp" ?

Comment: @schaiba - sorry don't remember! it was a long time ago and I moved to go :)