# cURL - put output into an integer variable

Tags: c++, curl, integer, libcurl

I am writing a c++ program that uses cURL and I am trying to read from a php file on a site into an integer variable.  I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577654/curl-put-output-into-variable) that is similar but I am having trouble adapting that to use an integer variable.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read into a string, then use atoi().

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of saying "thanks", here at SO we click the checkmark next to the right answer. :) This is called "Accepting".